# Cannot scroll content horizontal in windows store app

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

In my application, I have a StackPanel with the Orientation set to 'horizontal'. In my StackPanel there are 4 Images. When I try to scroll this content horizontally, it only scrolls a few pixels and I cannot see the whole content. When I change the Orientation of my StackPanel to vertical, I can scroll my whole content vertical. Why it isn't possible to scroll it hotizontally? Any ideas how I can solve this problem?

```
<Grid>
        <ScrollViewer>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                <Canvas Margin="120,0,0,0"
                        Width="310"
                        Height="390">
                    <Image Width="310"
                           Height="390" 
                           Source="ms-appx:///Assets/Image/background_teaser.png"/>
                </Canvas>

                <Canvas Margin="120,0,0,0"
                        Width="310"
                        Height="390">
                    <Image Width="310"
                           Height="390" 
                           Source="ms-appx:///Assets/Image/background_teaser.png"/>
                </Canvas>

                <Canvas Margin="120,0,0,0"
                        Width="310"
                        Height="390">
                    <Image Width="310"
                           Height="390" 
                           Source="ms-appx:///Assets/Image/background_teaser.png"/>
                </Canvas>

                <Canvas Margin="120,0,0,0"
                        Width="310"
                        Height="390">
                    <Image Width="310"
                           Height="390" 
                           Source="ms-appx:///Assets/Image/background_teaser.png"/>
                </Canvas>
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid
```

Comment: The property `Scroll` of the `ScrollViewer` is setted true for both directions?

Answer (score 3):

Horizontal scrolling is not enabled per default.

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollMode="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
```

Comment: As a note, @Matapolo may want to disable Vertical scrolling as well: `VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"`

Answer (score 0):

I had some issues working with Stackpanels in a ScrollViewer. Try wrapping the Stackpanel in another Grid.
And as the others have pointed out, you need to set the HorizontalScrollMode on your ScrollViewer